# WCF - Transport Security w/ message level encryption

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Is it possible to use both Transport security (HTTPS, authentication with a Client cert) in addition to message-level encryption via configuration in WCF?  Is this done with wsHttpBinding out-of-the-box?

I am attempting to accomplish this with a custom binding, but am unable to tell if the requests are being encrypted at the message level because they appear as plain text in the trace logs.

I've done quite a bit of research but can't seem to find any solid answers.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use Wireshark to find out whether they are encrypted or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have both [as described in this MSDN article.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashishme/archive/2009/05/06/windows-communication-foundation-transport-message-security-and-mutual-authentication.aspx) The article is pretty thorough & detailed but the crux of enabling this functionality is this setting:

```
 <!-- snipped -->
     <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp">
           <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
              <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                       negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
           </security>
        </binding>
     </wsHttpBinding>
 <!-- snipped -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm still a bit confused about the use of the "MessageCredential" in this scenario.  In this case, will the client certificate be used to encrypt the message in addition to authentication via the transport?

Comment: The article uses self-signed certificates to demonstrate how to configure a service with mutual certificate authentication. So the message credential is the client certificate that is used by the service for authentication. [This question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280819/wcf-how-do-i-encrypt-messages) has information that should help you understand message credentials. BTW: In production, you would use "real" certificates generated either by your organization or a cert vendor with this approach.

Comment: I'll add to this by offering up [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738565.aspx).  It's the best resource I've found to help understand how WCF configuration elements translate to WS Specifications.